# SQL Group By for multiple record

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I wrote a trigger it will fired whenever the table record is being updated or inserted for future process.

Because a record can be updated few times, my trigger table may have duplicated record. Eg. After insert, the person record may edited, and edited again so this will generated 3 records into trigger table. So what I need to do is Group by each duplicated record and check the latest record against the first record and update the rest status to 'OUTDATED'. Why latest and first because if the latest record type is delete which mean I no need to process any just update all to 'outdated' but if the first record is 'added' and subsequently record from update trigger, the record has the process with 'added' logic.

```
            SELECT \
            TYPE, PER_ID, CREATED_DATETIME \
            FROM \
            TRIGGER_TABLE \ 
            GROUP BY ...
            ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME DESC
```

Can anyone suggest a pseudocode how to phrase the Oracle SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SELECT \
        TYPE, PER_ID, CREATED_DATETIME \
        FROM \
        TRIGGER_TABLE as LatestRecord \
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 PER_ID
        FROM TRIGGER_TABLE AS FirstRecord
        WHERE LatestRecord.PER_ID = FirstRecord.PER_ID
        ORDER BY FirstRecord.CREATED_DATETIME ASC
        ) as EarliestRecord
        WHERE *Logic to compare EarlierRecord To Latest Record*
        ORDER BY LatestRecord.CREATED_DATETIME DESC
```

You could write an update based on the above query. The OUTER APPLY will return the earliest record with a matching PER_ID. You can then add any logic you need in the WHERE clause to compare the earlier and latest.